# dealing with thousand of data

Tags: apache-flex, loops, vector, actionscript

I have problems dealing with thousand of data.
The scenario is: looping through a collections (Vector.) with more than 40000 objects and draw only the items that don't overlap each other;
At the moment I do:
- I divide the area where I can draw in squares( a Vector. contains  all the points indentifying the squares);
- for each item in Vector. I loop through the squares to figure out wich area the item belongs to;
- I draw the first item in Vector. and I add the drawn item to a Vector. of drawn items
- for all the remains items I check if the item I have to draw overlaps the items already drawn in the belonging area looping through the Vector. of drawn items : if it doesn't overlap I draw it and add it to the Vector. of drawn items, if it overlaps I don't draw it.
To speed up the looping I'm using dictionary and vector, I'm declaring all the variable outside the loop and I'm also using the Duff's device for actionscript
My problem is the loop is still quite slow (about 9 seconds). Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Alex's pseudo-threading strategy.

http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html

```
 public class PseudoThread extends EventDispatcher
 {
     public function PseudoThread(sm:ISystemManager, threadFunction:Function, threadObject:Object)
     {
         fn = threadFunction;
         obj = threadObject;

         // add high priority listener for ENTER_FRAME
         sm.stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler, false, 100);
         sm.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
         sm.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

         thread = new UIComponent();
         sm.addChild(thread);
         thread.addEventListener(Event.RENDER, renderHandler);
     }

     // number of milliseconds we think it takes to render the screen
     public var RENDER_DEDUCTION:int = 10;

     private var fn:Function;
     private var obj:Object;
     private var thread:UIComponent;
     private var start:Number;
     private var due:Number;

     private var mouseEvent:Boolean;
     private var keyEvent:Boolean;

     private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
     {
        start = getTimer();
        var fr:Number = Math.floor(1000 / thread.systemManager.stage.frameRate);
        due = start + fr;

        thread.systemManager.stage.invalidate();
        thread.graphics.clear();
        thread.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
        thread.graphics.lineTo(0, 0);   
     }

     private function renderHandler(event:Event):void
     {
         if (mouseEvent || keyEvent)
             due -= RENDER_DEDUCTION;

         while (getTimer() < due)
         {
            if (!fn(obj))
            {
                if (!thread.parent)
                    return;

                var sm:ISystemManager = thread.systemManager;
                sm.stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
                sm.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
                sm.stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
                sm.removeChild(thread);
                thread.removeEventListener(Event.RENDER, renderHandler);
                dispatchEvent(new Event("threadComplete"));
            }
         }

         mouseEvent = false;
         keyEvent = false;
     }

     private function mouseMoveHandler(event:Event):void
     {
        mouseEvent = true;
     }

     private function keyDownHandler(event:Event):void
     {
        keyEvent = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Assuming this is not a mobile project, the asker could use actual threads using AS3 Workers, although this will help prevent prolonged inactivity.

Comment: It's not a mobile project. I'm not concerned about the UI freezing, but I need to speed up the function comparing the points I've already drawn. I think the suggested option (simulating multi threading) will solve only the freezing UI problem, but the whole process will always take more than the average 3 seconds I'm aiming to reach. A different approach rather than looping through drawn items is also welcome

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, vectors are slower than arrays.

Also, using:

```
var i:uint = 0;
for(i; i < v.length(); i++)
```

is faster than

```
for each(asdf in asdf)
```

(not sure how you're looping).

Also, consider shifting and creating arrays on the fly instead of one giant computation? Splitting it into different arrays might in the end require less calculations